# How can you group data by multiple fields with separate totals in SQL or Power query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, powerquery

I have a set of data that I want to count by multiple characteristics.

I am starting with something likes this (True/False for catagories)

| week | PP | SEN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T | F |
| 1 | T | T |
| 1 | F | F |
| 2 | T | F |
| 2 | T | T |
| 2 | F | F |
| 2 | F | F |
| 3 | T | F |
| 3 | F | F |

I want to end up with something along the lines of

| week | PP | SEN | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 |

As far as I can see I can only get something that would give me nested results

eg

| week | PP | SEN | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T | T | 1 |
| 1 | T | F | 1 |
| 1 | F | T | 0 |
| 1 | F | F | 1 |

It may be that this is really straight forward and I just have not found the correct search term, or it's just impossible via a query...but all suggestions welcome.

Comment: Are. you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select week, count(*) as total,
       sum(case when pp = 'T' then 1 else 0 end) as num_pp,
       sum(case when sen = 'T' then 1 else 0 end) as num_sen
from t
group by week;
```

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery, something like this

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Total", each "1"),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Custom", {"week"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Value", type text}}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type1","T","1",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Value"}),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","F","0",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Value"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value1",{{"Value", type number}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```